# How to play html video when its visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a tiktok ui project but video are not autoplay when it's on screen after scroll
Like tiktok
[Demo](https://eidramajan.blogspot.com/?m=1)

My code

```
        <div class="parent">
           <div class="vi"> 
            <video class="video-player" id="vid1" controls> <source src="https://writesonic.com/static/landingpage/dist/images/willscheren.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div>
       <div class="vi"> 
            <video class="video-player" id="vid1" controls> <source src="https://writesonic.com/static/landingpage/dist/images/willscheren.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div> <div class="vi"> 
            <video class="video-player" id="vid1" controls> <source src="https://writesonic.com/static/landingpage/dist/images/willscheren.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div> <div class="vi"> 
            <video class="video-player" controls> <source src="https://writesonic.com/static/landingpage/dist/images/willscheren.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div> <div class="vi"> 
            <video class="video-player" controls> <source src="https://writesonic.com/static/landingpage/dist/images/willscheren.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div>
              


  </div>

    <script>
function isOnScreen(element)
{
    var curPos = element.offset();
    var curTop = curPos.top;
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    return (curTop > screenHeight) ? false : true;
}

if(isOnScreen($('video'))) {
console.log("")

 };
    </script>
```

Please solve this issue with javascript or jQuery

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: when i check the demo, only if i click on the video screen, it works! do you want that?
If so you can add different id to each video element and try like this.
<video id="video1" onClick="playPause();">

Comment: I want autoplay like tiktok and instagram reel

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
var remoteVideo = document.createElement("video"); /*your Video element */
remoteVideo.id = `xxx_ID`;
remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
remoteVideo.playsInline = true; /* For Safari fix */
```

or

```
remoteVideo.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give attribute "autoplay" to each video tag like this.

```
 <video class="video-player" controls **autoplay**> <source src="https://writesonic.com/static/landingpage/dist/images/willscheren.mp4" type="video/mp4" > </video>
```

Comment: But with this attribute , all video are playing in same time , I want to play one video ones like tiktok

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add video components on the fly, rather than writing links directly in HTML.